# "NotImplementedError: wxGCDC is not available on this platform" in wxPython

Tags: python, linux, wxpython, wxwidgets

I installed wxPython 2.8.12.1 from the source on my linux with the xfce4 desktop environment using the following config:

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/wx/2.8 --build=i686-pc-linux --disable-precomp-headers --without-opengl --enable-graphics_ctx
```

As a result I got the following error:

```
dc: <wx._gdi.BufferedPaintDC; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxBufferedPaintDC *' at 0x5e3550> >
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gra.py", line 15, in OnPaint
    gc = wx.GCDC(dc)
  File "/opt/staff/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/wxPython/wx/_gdi.py", line 6068, in __init__
    _gdi_.GCDC_swiginit(self,_gdi_.new_GCDC(*args))
NotImplementedError: wxGCDC is not available on this platform.
```

during the process of execution of this line of code:

```
gc = wx.GCDC(dc)
```

What's the problem? How I can make wxGCDC available on my platform?

Unfortunately I have to install wxPython from the source (cannot use the precompiled version of this library).

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you should really build wxPython 3.0 and not 2.8, especially as you build it yourself anyhow.

Comment: No, I cannot use wxPython 3.0, because there is no backwards compatibility with 2.8 version. If I use wxPython 2.8 I'll have to rewrite some part of my app.

Comment: @MindMixer, 2.8 is pretty old, maybe it is time to move up to a newer version?  Depending on your application you might even want to give a try and use wxPython Phoenix.

Answer (score 1):

wxGCDC will not be available if wxGraphicsConext is not included in the wxWidgets build, and it needs to be turned on in the configure options when wxWidgets is built.  (And, IIRC, it may be automatically turned off again if certain dependent libraries are not installed.)  So check your build of wxWidgets, and watch the output of configure to make sure the graphics context option is enabled.  If you're not also building it yourself you may want to consider doing so.

And I'll also reccommend that you switch up to wxPython 3.0.x (classic).  It is mostly compatible with 2.8.12 and should not require many changes in your code. In addition, 3.0.x has a large number of fixes and additions, and is a good stepping stone to the new Phoenix version of wxPython that is coming.

Comment: Oops, I just took a closer look at your message and noticed that you are running conifgure and you are enabling the graphics context.  You'll still want to take that close look at the output though and verify that it is actually enabled, and if not, why.  Also make sure that the wxPython build is using the wxWidgets you built and not some other one that may have already been installed.

Comment: I checked the configure output:checking for --enable-graphics_ctx... yes

Comment: I deleted /opt/wx/2.8 and execute make install again. The same problem :(

Comment: I also checked in this way: `nm -D /opt/wx/2.8/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so | grep wxGCDC` and got a lot of results of matching

Comment: Do you see anything in the configure output about Cairo?  (Such as "Cairo library not found" or "Cairo library is too old")